# How to disable AUCTeX highlighting?

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, auctex

I'm trying to use GNU Emacs 26.3 + AUCTeX 12.2.3 and it seems to work, but the colors it shows in the source code are very annoying, specially in amsmath environment such as align, because it uses only one color for the whole block. I would like to ignore auctex highlighting so the code looks the same as before installing auctex package, this is something like this: [source code before AUCTeX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elsbN.png)

I deleted some strings like "align" from "Font Latex Math Environments" so it doesn't use the font locking for math environments, and now it looks like normal text: [current source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Kjq.png)

It's better that one color, yes, but there are several commands that doesn't highlight and I would like them to. (Not highlighted commands occurs outside the align too). Another option would be adding a generic alphabetic string next to `\` as a keyword so it would be highlighted but I also don't know how to achieve this.